# Новый random при каждом обращении к боту

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

В тексте файла - URL-ссылки.
Бот успешно отправляет в ответ рандомную ссылку из документа, но при повторном вызове команды "/start" ссылка не меняется. Как создать цикл, который будет постоянно менять рандомное значение при вызове команды ?

```
import telebot
import random

bot = telebot.TeleBot('0000000000:0000000000PFlZqtPNZtPF-oJYXkehL_Ijk')

choicefile=open("files.txt")
linelist=[]
for line in choicefile:
    linelist.append(line)
choice=random.choice(linelist)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, choice)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling()
```

Comment: Просто перенесите строку `choice=random.choice(linelist)` внутрь функции `start_message`. Никакого больше цикла "создавать" не нужно, нужно просто вызывать `random.choice` в момент получения сообщения ботом, а у вас сейчас вызывается только при старте программы.

Comment: Благодарю! Решено.

Answer (score 0):

Строку `choice=random.choice(linelist)`

Необходимо перенести внутрь функции `start_message`

*Ответ дан от пользователя @insolor из комментариев.*

Я бы также порекомендовал занести код в функцию и обращаться к ей при необходимости, чтобы не засорять функцию ответа на сообщение `'/start'`:

```
choice = ''

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    global choice     <------ Позволяет изменить переменную и прочитать её содержимое
    randie(message)   <------ Обращение к функции, обязательно передаём параметр message
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{choice}')    <------ Используем форматирование

def randie(message):  <------ Имя функции может быть любым
    global choice     <------ Здесь всё также
    choicefile=open("files.txt")
    linelist=[]
    for line in choicefile:
        linelist.append(line)
    choice=random.choice(linelist)
```

Comment: Если уж вызываете randie из start_message, то не нужно использовать global, а нужно просто вернуть значение из функции. Вообще стоит избегать использования global. К тому же теперь список из файла читается при каждом сообщении, что не оптимально - изначальный вариант кода обращался к файлу только один раз. Еще и файл после чтения не закрываете - понятно что это в изначальном коде так, но раз уж исправляете, то исправляйте до конца.

Answer (score 0):

Перенесите choice=random.choice(linelist) в start_message